# AWS PHP PDO MySQL Connection Problem SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo

I am trying to connect to my AWS MYSQL database following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html#php-rds-connect.

My Code

```
<?php
$dbhost = $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'];
$dbport = $_SERVER['RDS_PORT'];
$dbname = $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'];
$charset = 'utf8' ;

$dsn = "mysql:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}";
$username = $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'];
$password = $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
?>
```

The output

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I am able to connect to my database with MySQL Workbench.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you get the answer to this? I am having the same problem too

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your Database  settings. May be  it's a wrong port setting.If you use localhost you can try to change the host to 127.0.0.1.  The MySQL process might be stuck.